# Moving a Java Swing Graphic

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I want to recreate a game I made in Python and after learning the basics of Swing, I moved on to drawing Graphics. Now I'm stuck. I created a black square and would like to move its coordinates by 10 to the right. What I want is to be able to make an animation by moving the square and be able to respond to the user's actions. Right now all I want is when the window is created (now), at run time for the square to be redrawn 10 pixels to the right.

In Python Tkinter this was easy:

```
square = myCanvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 20, 20)
```

then later in the code, I would do this:

```
x = 10
while True:
    x = x + 10
    myCanvas.coords(square, x, y, x+10, y+20)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    myMainWindow.update()
```

It would move the square to the right for ever.

Here is my Java code:

```
package tutorial2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tutorial2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        make_gui();
    }
    static void make_gui(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame("My Window");
        f.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyRectangle extends Rectangle{
    Rectangle self;
    int x;
    int y;
    public MyRectangle(int x, int y){
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.self = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, this.x+10, this.y+10);
    }

}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    MyRectangle user = new MyRectangle(10, 10);
    Rectangle user2 = new Rectangle(30, 30, 40, 40);
    public MyPanel(){

    };

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        //graphics2d.fill(user2);
        graphics2d.fill(user.self);
    }
}
```

How do I do it in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
g.drawRect(x1,y1,width,height);
```

Or:

```
g.fillRect(x1,y1,width,height);
```

You don't need a `Rectangle` object or your own `MyRectangle` object.

You can store the coordinates and update them every frame.

Comment: I'm doing it so that later I can just update the rectangle's x and y and have an automatic loop which updates the rectangle. Could you please provide an example of what you wrote?

Comment: @user3700465 Sure... You need to call the `repaint()` of the `JFrame` in a while loop in the main method.

Comment: Nah, it proves a point, but the point isn't really a point for the person himself reading the point, which doesn't in fact understand the point. (e.g me).

Comment: +1 Now I'm getting somewhere. So from my understanding, I have to repaint my frame using `frame.repaint()` in the `public static void main`. But from my understanding of Java Swing, I can't do it there because I want the square to move at a later time e.g. click of a button (when the main has already loaded). So... um... my mind is blank.

Comment: @user3700465 Actually, with Swing, I'm not sure. I usually use better libraries for games, and only use Swing for applications. With those applications, I only update my components when something happens: ie a user types something or clicks on something.

Comment: @user3700465 Wait what do you want to do? You want the rectangle to move when?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55443/discussion-between-anubian-noob-and-user3700465).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE : put it through an IDE now. The class should be compilable**

Certainly have a Rectangle class, but include a draw and move method.

```
class MyRectangle {

    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void makeBigger(int value) {
        width = width + value;
        height = height + value;
    }
}
```

You just need to create the object, and call it in a loop from a panel or some other component like a canvas.

For example you could override the paintComponent(..) method in a panel, and use a thread or timer to create the animation in a loop.

```
class myPanel extends JPanel{


    MyRectangle r = new MyRectangle(10,10,10,10);

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        r.makeBigger(10);
        r.draw(g);
    }

}
```

This panel would have to be repainted in a timer action or can just be added to a button action. The action code would look like thie :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    myPanel.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Better yet use a graphics library to do this for you. If you want to make your game you should watch youtube videos learn the basics to game applications and you will pick it up easily.

Comment: I already have the game. It's just a matter of converting it to Java. You said `use the graphics library`. Could you please expand on that point including an example?

Comment: In Java, Swing 2D animation requires hundreds and hundreds of lines of code.  We can't just hand them all over to you.  You can read my [Horse Race GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=425) article to see how to put an animated Swing application together.